# How to change gradient colors in svg-edit?

Tags: svg-edit

How can I select the colors for a linear gradient in svg-edit?

The "Change fill color" popup lets me select a gradient, which seems to be based on the current solid color of the shape. But there is no color-picker for either vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-click the circled "start" and "end" points in the screenshot:

[image: Start and end]

Comment: Sorry, for me its not working, tested via https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/latest/editor/svg-editor.html

Comment: Not working in which browser? and which exact steps do you follow?

Comment: Im using Chrome 73.0.3683.86 (64-bit) on Windows 7 Professional. I can open the gradient tab, but double-clicking on any of the nodes has no effect. I would expect some kind of color-picker to pop up?

Comment: Oh, my apologies... I should have checked in Chrome--was using Firefox. I see confirmed. Please file as a bug.

Comment: actually, my apologies again, I forgot there already is an issue filed: https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit/issues/181 so feel free to subscribe or comment there . I'll try to see if the suggested fix can still work in our much-since-changed code.

Comment: The issue is now fixed in `master`--not sure when I'll get to updating npm and the site.